# Pandas - ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching type

Tags: pandas

I have this piece of code:

```
self.value=0.8

for col in df.ix[:,'value1':'value3']:
    df = df.iloc[abs(df[col] - self.value).argsort()]
```

which works perfectly as part of `main()` function. at return, it prints:

```
    artist          track                      pos     neg          neu
4   Sufjan Stevens       Casimir Pulaski Day   0.09    0.91          0.0
9   Sufjan Stevens            The Only Thing   0.09    0.91          0.0
5        Radiohead        Desert Island Disk   0.08    0.92          0.0
0   Sufjan Stevens  Should Have Known Better   0.07    0.93          0.0
1   Sufjan Stevens      To Be Alone With You   0.05    0.95          0.0
8        Radiohead               Daydreaming   0.05    0.95          0.0
3   Sufjan Stevens        Death with Dignity   0.03    0.97          0.0
11   Elliott Smith          Between the Bars   0.03    0.97          0.0
2     Jeff Buckley                Hallelujah   0.39    0.61          0.0
6        Radiohead                     Codex   0.00    1.00          0.0
7       Aphex Twin                Avril 14th   0.00    1.00          0.0
10       Radiohead       You And Whose Army?   0.00    1.00          0.0
```

however, when I import this function as part of a module, and even though I'm passing and printing the same `0.8 self.value`, I get the following error:

```
    df = df.iloc[(df[col] - self.flavor).argsort()]
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 721, in wrapper
    result = wrap_results(safe_na_op(lvalues, rvalues))
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 682, in safe_na_op
    return na_op(lvalues, rvalues)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 668, in na_op
    result[mask] = op(x[mask], y)
TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S32') dtype('S32') dtype('S32')
```

why is it so? what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `pd.DataFrame.ix` is has been deprecated.  You should stop using it.
2. Your use of `'value1':'value3'` is dangerous as it can include columns you didn't expect if your columns aren't positioned in the order you thought.

   ```
   df = pd.DataFrame(
       [['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3]],
       columns='artist track v1 v2 v3'.split()
   )

   list(df.loc[:, 'v1':'v3'])

   ['v1', 'v2', 'v3']
   ```

   But rearrange the columns and

   ```
   list(df.loc[:, ['v1', 'v2', 'artist', 'v3', 'b']].loc[:, 'v1':'v3'])

   ['v1', 'v2', 'artist', 'v3']
   ```

   You got `'artist'` in the the list.  And column `'artist'` is of type string and can't be subtracted from or by an integer or float.

   ```
   df['artist'] - df['v1']

   > TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')
   ```

---

**Setup**
*Shuffle `df`*

```
df = df.sample(frac=1)
df

            artist                     track     pos     neg     neu
0   Sufjan Stevens  Should Have Known Better    0.07    0.93     0.0
8        Radiohead               Daydreaming    0.05    0.95     0.0
1   Sufjan Stevens      To Be Alone With You    0.05    0.95     0.0
5        Radiohead        Desert Island Disk    0.08    0.92     0.0
11   Elliott Smith          Between the Bars    0.03    0.97     0.0
7       Aphex Twin                Avril 14th    0.00    1.00     0.0
2     Jeff Buckley                Hallelujah    0.39    0.61     0.0
4   Sufjan Stevens       Casimir Pulaski Day    0.09    0.91     0.0
9   Sufjan Stevens            The Only Thing    0.09    0.91     0.0
3   Sufjan Stevens        Death with Dignity    0.03    0.97     0.0
6        Radiohead                     Codex    0.00    1.00     0.0
10       Radiohead       You And Whose Army?    0.00    1.00     0.0
```

---

**Solution**
Use `np.lexsort`

```
value = 0.8

v = df[['pos', 'neg', 'neu']].values

df.iloc[np.lexsort(np.abs(v - value).T)]

            artist                     track     pos     neg     neu
4   Sufjan Stevens       Casimir Pulaski Day    0.09    0.91     0.0
9   Sufjan Stevens            The Only Thing    0.09    0.91     0.0
5        Radiohead        Desert Island Disk    0.08    0.92     0.0
0   Sufjan Stevens  Should Have Known Better    0.07    0.93     0.0
8        Radiohead               Daydreaming    0.05    0.95     0.0
1   Sufjan Stevens      To Be Alone With You    0.05    0.95     0.0
11   Elliott Smith          Between the Bars    0.03    0.97     0.0
3   Sufjan Stevens        Death with Dignity    0.03    0.97     0.0
2     Jeff Buckley                Hallelujah    0.39    0.61     0.0
7       Aphex Twin                Avril 14th    0.00    1.00     0.0
6        Radiohead                     Codex    0.00    1.00     0.0
10       Radiohead       You And Whose Army?    0.00    1.00     0.0
```

Comment: oh, great. but I took the liberty of editing the question and changing col names, given the fact `regex`is now necessary...could you be so kind and rewrite the matches in order to contemplate the real col names?..

Comment: regex is not necessary.  Just use the three columns names.  I will update.